# Запрос MYSQL с выбором CASE

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица с картинками

```
CREATE TABLE `ProductPhoto` (
      `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `path` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `productId` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
      `position` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'позиция картинки в списке изображений товара',
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=23376 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

К одному продукту относятся много картинок, но не у всех продуктов выставлена позиция - она может быть у всех картинок продукта NULL, может быть 1 позицией (могут встречаться с другими позициями в рамках одного продукта) 
А как отобразить path первой картинки продукта, при этом сделав проверку - если он есть - отдать, в противном случае вернуть картинку с наименьшим id?
единственно что пришло в голову так это

```
SELECT p.* ,
(SELECT 
  CASE 
  WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ProductPhoto WHERE productId = p.id AND position = 1) 
    THEN (SELECT path FROM ProductPhoto WHERE productId = p.id AND position = 1) 
  ELSE (SELECT path FROM ProductPhoto WHERE productId = p.id ORDER BY id LIMIT 1)
  END) AS `photo`
FROM Product p LIMIT 15
```

Заложено ли в синтаксисе SQL более легковесные конструкции языка, позволяющие сделать ту же логику с меньшим количеством обращений, вычислений ?

Comment: Да идеологически просто `ORDER BY position LIMIT 1`. Что синтаксически превращается в коррелированный подзапрос в SELECT или дополнительный подзапрос во FROM.

Comment: я пробовал ставить ORDER BY position - у меня сперва выдавались строчки в которых стоит NULL  !!!

Comment: Так и должно быть... в условии не очень определено, что, где и как.. я поначалу понял, что приоритеты либо не заданы (везде null), либо заданы (null отсутствует). Но если null и not null перемешаны, то это будет либо `ORDER BY position IS NOT NULL, position`, либо `ORDER BY position = 1, position` - смотря куда следует пихать NULL-ы.

Comment: ORDER BY position IS NOT NULL - спасибо - я такой конструкции не видел ни в одном электронном справочнике - можете прикрепить источник

Comment: [IS NOT NULL operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is-not-null)

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html   - там ничего не сказано про такую конструкцию - допускается ASC || DESC      IS NOT NULL применяется только в логических выражениях

Comment: Так `position IS NOT NULL` и есть логическое выражение...